# android location emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, location

i'm trying to use android emulator for eclipse.
i've set my emulator geo point using both telnet and emulator ddms.

for some reason when i'm trying to get my location from the emulator it always return 0,0 to me.
i think maybe i'm not getting it from the right location provide. which of the providers should be use in the emulator ?

this is my code:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location == null) {
            location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (location == null) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Couldn't get your location, map will be unavailable",
                        8000).show();
            }
            else
            {
                app.setLatitude((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6));
                app.setLongitude((int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
            }
        } else {
            app.setLatitude((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6));
            app.setLongitude((int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these telnet commands to set a GPS fix and location in the emulator:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#geo

```
geo <fix|nmea>
```

Comment: i've done it.. and then when trying to:
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps");
   Log.e("gps", Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
i get a null pointer exeption